# 2 rails engines in 1 project, view problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-engines

Currently i'm developing 2 Rails::Engines 1 blog (for fun) and 1 csv importer and mapper. I made them with enginex and jeweler into a gem. I installed them locally and i included either 1 of them in an empty rails 3.x project and it's working fine!

The thing i want to do know is include *both* gems in 1 rails 3.x project. This all works doesn't raise any errors but here is the problem.

When i go to my "/blog" routes everything is rendered perfectly. But when i go to my "/csv" route i dont see any layouts. When i look at the development.log i see this:

```
Started GET "/csv" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun May 01 20:23:19 +0200 2011
Processing by CsvEngine::ImportsController#index as HTML
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/csv_engine-0.0.1/app/views/csv_engine/imports/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 23.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

This all looks fine, but i dont see any of my html. But when i put a `<%= raise "hell %>` inside my index.html.erb it gets raised. So i'm baffled here, both my engines work. All my rails logic works but i dont see my html inside the index.html.erb.

The strangest thing is when i include "csv_engine" gem without the blog gem in a empty rails 3 app everything works fine and i get the html views.

I even tried overwriting the views from within my empty host app e.g. `app/views/csv_engine/imports/index.html.erb` with some other html in it but this also doesnt work.
Does anyone has any idea what this could be?

Comment: Show us the code for `CsvEngine::ImportsController` please.

Comment: enginex Rails Engines were just for Rails 3.1.x. Could it be that you new app is Rails => 3.1?